# Kubernetes Kibana 8.5.2 Statefulset healthcheck path? Tried /login but "connection refused"

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, kubernetes-health-check, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

Kibana `Statefulset`:

```
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: HTTPS
              path: /login
              port: 5601
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 3
            successThreshold: 1
```

Kibana `ConfigMap`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kibana-config
  namespace: default
data:
  kibana.yml: |+
    csp.strict: true
    server.port: 5601
    server.host: "0.0.0.0"
    elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://elasticsearch-es-default:9200"]
    xpack.security.enabled: true
    elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: config/certs/client-ca.cer
    elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: certificate
```

Comment: what was kibana pod's log?

Answer (score 0):

Kibana is the frontend service for elasticsearch so when we are deploying a statefulset ELK, we will be doing the health check of the elasticsearch cluster(This I got from referring various sources on statefulset deployment of ELK stack on kubernetes). This is one such [document](https://devopscube.com/setup-efk-stack-on-kubernetes/) describing the statefulset deployment of ELK stack on kubernetes, refer to it for more information.